# fullCalendar - Return results other than using indexOf()

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, fullcalendar

Good day!

I have this property:

```
eventRender: function (event, element, view) {
        return ['', event.number].indexOf($('#number').val()) >= 0;
    }
events: [
     // ....other data
     number: // contains data that is not an integer, assigned keywords to this instead
]
```

And in this property, I have a function that returns me events that specifically have the keyword that I enter in my search input. It works great and it does show me the events that have the keyword, however, I'm trying to achieve getting results that match such letters, words, etc in that event.

```
<input type="text" id="number" placeholder="">
```

I have tried: `indexOf() <- default/works fine, includes() <- does not even return me results, match() <- also does nothing`

In my code, what areas can I improve to get the results without using ***indexOf()***? I hope I did my best to explaining my issue and asking the question, and I hope to learn from this to better improve my code.

Comment: `indexOf() <- default/works fine` what does it mean? When you use indexOf on the array, does it return the index? `includes()` doesn't return i.e it is unable to find it in array? Can you add the content of `['', event.number]` ?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara yes it returns the index, but in other words, it returns events that has only that keyword when an event has other keywords along it. I want to be able to return the event(s) that has different keywords and not just that one keyword.

Comment: If it is possible, can you add your expectations in the question with a sample of input?

Comment: The output that I expect to have would be: the calendar to return an event that contains the keyword entered, but also can be returned with another keyword and not just the first keyword entered. Because in my database, I have multiple keywords for different events. @ApoorvaChikara

Comment: In that case, you can create an array of events and when you receive any new keyword that is mapped to your events push it to this array. It is tough to answer without having the expectation in form of code.

Comment: I have a column that has keywords in a form of array ("keyword, keyword, keyword"). However, when I search an event using one of the keywords, it doesn't return the event. I would have to type all those keywords in that form of array and then it will return me that event. @ApoorvaChikara

Answer (score 0):

You need to create keywords like the below array. It seems `["keyword, keyword, keyword"]` is only one sting in an array please mind quotes to create keyword - should be `["keyword", "keyword", "keyword"]`

```js
const keywords = ["click", "click1", "click3"];
const log = console.log;
function checkEvent(event) {
  // return keywords.indexOf(event) !== -1; 
  return keywords.includes(event);
}

log(checkEvent("click1"));
log(checkEvent("click3"));
log(checkEvent("click32"));
```